# Adding Controls to View Without IG

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I have a very simple question--it is so simple that I find it a bit embarrassing.  How do I add controls to a view when I do not have access to the window from the appdelegate class.  Here is a screen that I traverse to from it.  (this is just the viewdidload method)

I thought window.AddSubview(btnSubmit); would work, but window is not recognized outside of the appdelegate class.

```
public override void ViewDidLoad ()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad ();

        var btnSubmit = UIButton.FromType (UIButtonType.RoundedRect);
        var frame = new System.Drawing.RectangleF (35f, 30f, 250f, 40f);
        btnSubmit.Frame = frame;
        btnSubmit.SetTitle ("Return Home", UIControlState.Highlighted);

        btnSubmit.TouchUpInside += (sender, e) =>
        {
            btnSubmit.SetTitle("Clicked", UIControlState.Normal);
        };


        // Perform any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use View.AddSubview()

```
this.View.AddSubview(btnSubmit);
```